# Dynamic XmlRootElement for object

Tags: c#, web-services, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I'm working on a project that makes use of the ImgUr.com API
I request an image, or an album, and the XML is returned.

I'm using a Serializer to Deserialize the XML back into an object. So I made classes for both Image and Album.

But here comes the tricky part...
An album looks something like this:

```
<data success="1" result="200">
  <id>x</id>
  ...
  <images>
    <item>
      <id>x</id>
      <link>http://linktoimage.jpg</link>
      ...
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>x</id>
      <link>http://linktoimage.jpg</link>
      ...
    </item>
    ...
  </images>
</data>
```

So the root-element of the actual image is 'item'.

But when I request the actual image through the API, i get the following:

```
<data success="1" result="200">
  <id>x</id>
  <link>http://linktoimage.jpg</link>
  ...
</data>
```

Now, the root element is 'data'.

So the solution I have now is two different classes. One with  `[XMLRootElement(Elementname = "item")]` and one with `[XMLRootElement(Elementname = "data")]` but I guess there should be a simplere solution to this?

**Edit**: 
By request of Henk, my receiving-part
The code I have for recieving the XML:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}image/{1}.xml",     Settings.Default.ImgUrBaseUrl, albumId));
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID " + Settings.Default.ImgUrClientID);

var response = request.GetResponse();
var imageStream = response.GetResponseStream();
if (imageStream == null) return "";
var serilizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ImgUrSingleImage));
var result = serilizer.Deserialize(imageStream) as ImgUrSingleImage;
```

So, I guess I need to take out the `<data>` tag, and wrap the remaining xml in a new `<item>` tag?

Comment: Looks like a not too serializer-friendly format. You can easily pre-process the XML to insert an `<item>` tag.

Comment: @HenkHolterman You mean something like reading the xml as a string, replacing `<data` for  `<item` and `</data>` for `</item>`?

Comment: I assume you have a string, I would prefer mutation through an XElement. And maybe insert rather than replace tags, it depends.

Comment: I read the xml through a Streamreader. I'll have to dive into the XElement.

Comment: When you post the reading/receiving part you could get some help.

Comment: I will post it when I'm at home. Can't get to my code from the office ;)

Comment: i'll post my code as an answer, i guess (kind of new here :))

Comment: No, don't do that. Edit the question.

Comment: Done, I editted the original question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert an `<image>` tag like this:

```
var imageStream = response.GetResponseStream();
if (imageStream == null) return "";

XElement doc = XElement.Load(imageStream);            
XElement item = new XElement("item", doc.Elements());
doc.ReplaceNodes(item);
var reader = new StringReader(doc.ToString());

var serilizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ImgUrSingleImage));
var result = serilizer.Deserialize(reader) as ImgUrSingleImage;
```

and then your `ImgUrSingleImage` class should have a single `Item` property that is in common with the list request.

Alternatively you can skip the `<data>` tag and directly deserialize from the `item` XElement.